# VBA and XML: How can I access certain data when attribute name is the same?

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I am using excel vba to get specific attributes within an XML file (working with XML is a new adventure for me).  After looking through dozens of tutorials and blogs, I can't find anything that shows me how to get some of the attributes I need from my XML file due to the format of the XML.

This is the basic format of the XML file:

```
<CHECKLIST>
    <STIG_INFO>
        <STIG_TITLE>Active Directory Domain Security Technical Implementation Guide (STIG)</STIG_TITLE>
    </STIG_INFO>
    <VULN>
        <STIG_DATA>
            <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Vuln_Num</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>V-8521</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
        </STIG_DATA>
        <STIG_DATA>
            <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Severity</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>low</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
        </STIG_DATA>
        <STIG_DATA>
            <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Group_Title</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>Object Ownership Delegation</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
        </STIG_DATA>
        <STIG_DATA>
            <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Rule_ID</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>SV-9018r3_rule</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
        </STIG_DATA>
    <STATUS>NotAFinding</STATUS>
     </VULN>
     <VULN>
        <STIG_DATA>
            <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Vuln_Num</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>V-8522</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
        </STIG_DATA>
        <STIG_DATA>
            <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Severity</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>medium</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
        </STIG_DATA>
        <STIG_DATA>
            <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Group_Title</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>Directory Service Inter-Enclave VPN Usage</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
        </STIG_DATA>
        <STIG_DATA>
            <VULN_ATTRIBUTE>Rule_ID</VULN_ATTRIBUTE>
            <ATTRIBUTE_DATA>SV-30991r3_rule</ATTRIBUTE_DATA>
        </STIG_DATA>
    <STATUS>NotAFinding</STATUS>
     </VULN>
</CHECKLIST>
```

I am trying to access all of the Vulnerability Number, the Rule ID, and the Status values.  So far I have only been successful in getting the Status values using the code below, but I can't seem to figure out how to get to the Vunerability Number and Rule ID.  For example, my all_Vuln_Num returns every ATTRIBUTE_DATA in the XML file.  My all_Rule_ID returns nothing.

```
Dim filename As String
filename = "C:\myfile.xml"
Set xmlChecklist = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlChecklist.async = False
xmlChecklist.validateOnParse = False
xmlChecklist.Load (filename)
Set all_Vuln_Num = xmlChecklist.SelectNodes("//CHECKLIST/VULN/STIG_DATA/ATTRIBUTE_DATA[0]/text()")
Set all_Rule_ID = xmlChecklist.SelectNodes("//CHECKLIST/VULN/STIG_DATA/ATTRIBUTE_DATA[3]/text()")
Set vuln_Status = xmlChecklist.SelectNodes("//CHECKLIST/VULN/STATUS/text()")
```

Comment: Hello Jorge, please take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx for a beginners guide to MSXML. You can add the reference to MSXML 5.0 in the VBA -> Tools -> Add reference. (Warning, some older versions of excel don't have 5.0 installed, or newer don't have 3.0 installed) Using these libraries instead might help you avoid some issues (like not being able to get the nodes you want) and learn more about xml!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figured it out after looking at the pattern in the XML file again.  I used this code instead and now have access to all of the data I need.  Unfortunately, it is highly dependent on the attributes appearing in the same order in every XML file, but it's a start I suppose!

```
Set all_Vuln_Num = xmlChecklist.SelectNodes("//CHECKLIST/VULN/STIG_DATA[0]/ATTRIBUTE_DATA")
Set all_Rule_ID = xmlChecklist.SelectNodes("//CHECKLIST/VULN/STIG_DATA[3]/ATTRIBUTE_DATA")
Set vuln_Status = xmlChecklist.SelectNodes("//CHECKLIST/VULN/STATUS")
```